# How to get UIButton frame X position in Swift (UIKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiview, cgrect

I want to make my blue underline start and end within the red frame.
So, I'm trying to get the X position, the starting position of my UIButton. The red one (red is a bg color).
How can I do that?

[image]

Things I've tried:

```
promoButton.frame.origin.x
```

or

```
promoButton.bounds.origin.x
```

result: 0.0

```
promoButton.layer.position.x
```

This actually move the underline, but it started at the 'P' of 'Promo' instead of the red frame.

Can anyone tell me how to get the frame X position?

Thankyou in advance.

---

Update:

This is how i put it in the storyboard:

First there is this Tab View

[image]

Next, I have the container

[image]

Then the Promo button it self

[image]

I guess 0.0 is because it's inside a view. but is it possible to calculate X position from the screen tho?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code that reproduces the screenshot.

Comment: Add  where you use that code , meaning context of the problem

Comment: Please re-check my post @Sweeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with auto-layout / constraints, so you don't need to worry about "frames."

We'll setup the Storyboard like this - note: we are NOT adding the "underline view" in the Storyboard:

[image]

I've given the "container view" and the buttons different background colors to make it easier to see the framing.

We'll make `@IBOutlet` connections to the three buttons:

```
@IBOutlet var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btn3: UIButton!
```

and we'll connect the `Touch Up Inside` for all buttons to the same function.

In `viewDidLoad()` we'll create and add the `underlineView`, and give it a `Height` constraint of `4.0`. It looks like you want it about 8-points below the buttons, so we'll also give it a `Top` constraint relative to the Bottom of the first button (doesn't really matter which button, as we're assuming they are the same).

Now, we'll add two class properties:

```
var underlineLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var underlineWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Again in `viewDidLoad()` we'll create those two constraints, and set them related to `btn1`.

When we tap a button, we'll:

- deactivate those two constraints
- re-make them related to the **tapped** button
- and animate the change

  @IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  // de-activate the underline view constraints
  underlineLeadingConstraint.isActive = false
  underlineWidthConstraint.isActive = false

  ```
    // re-create the Leading and Width constraints
    //  related to the tapped button
    underlineLeadingConstraint = underlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.leadingAnchor)
    underlineWidthConstraint = underlineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.widthAnchor)

    // activate those new constraints
    underlineLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
    underlineWidthConstraint.isActive = true

    // if you want to animate it
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
  ```

  }

Here's the complete controller class:

```
class UnderlineViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btn2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btn3: UIButton!

    var underlineView: UIView!
    
    var underlineLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var underlineWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        underlineView = UIView()
        underlineView.backgroundColor = .blue
        underlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(underlineView)
        
        // underlineView height is 4-points
        underlineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4.0).isActive = true
        
        // looks like you want it about 8-points below the button bottom?
        underlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        
        // create Leading and Width constraints for the underlineView
        underlineLeadingConstraint = underlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.leadingAnchor)
        underlineWidthConstraint = underlineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.widthAnchor)
        // activate those constraints
        underlineLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
        underlineWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        
    }

    @IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // de-activate the underline view constraints
        underlineLeadingConstraint.isActive = false
        underlineWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        
        // re-create the Leading and Width constraints
        //  related to the tapped button
        underlineLeadingConstraint = underlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.leadingAnchor)
        underlineWidthConstraint = underlineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sender.widthAnchor)
        
        // activate those new constraints
        underlineLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
        underlineWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        
        // if you want to animate it
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    
}
```

Here's how it looks when running:

[image]

Since we are now using constraints - instead of calculating frame coordinates - the underline width and position will automatically update when the "tab buttons" change... such as on device rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [convert(_:, to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace/1622564-convert) method available on `UIView` in order to convert between coordinate spaces, for example:

```swift
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50))
let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
let subcontainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 250, height: 250))

container.addSubview(subcontainer)
subcontainer.addSubview(button)

let buttonFrameWithinContainer = button.convert(button.bounds, to: container) // returns { 170, 170, 50, 50 }
```